# Change background image REACTJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an img tag in react. I'm using that for style background.
But that code is throwing an error.

```
<img className="user-avatar" style={{ background:"url("+{obj.producer_info.avatar_url}+")"  }} id="first-user" src="img/fillavt.png" />
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: this code is problem :'(

Comment: You need to add more context. Maybe the var obj does not exist. May you please copy the whole render function?

Comment: Well `{ background:"url("+{obj.producer_info.avatar_url}+")"  }` this is just invalid syntax.

Comment: haha you're right :-D I just didn't realize it, because I was searching for a deeper sense of the question than just some syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs of all, take advantage of the new string concatenation syntax:

```
<img className="user-avatar" style={{ background:`url(${obj.producer_info.avatar_url})`}} id="first-user" src="img/fillavt.png" />
```

So in first place you reduce complexity on opening/closing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify a variable within `{}` when you are doing string concatenation. You could simply do

```
<img className="user-avatar" style={{ background:"url("+obj.producer_info.avatar_url+")"  }} id="first-user" src="img/fillavt.png"
```

or else make use of [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<img className="user-avatar" style={{ background:`url(${obj.producer_info.avatar_url})`  }} id="first-user" src="img/fillavt.png"
```